# React-hook-form on submit and useState issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Hey so im facing this strange issue while using react-hook-form.

This is the gist of my code

```
const [error, setError] = useState(true)

const onSubmit = values => {
    setError(false)
    console.log(error) // true on first click and false on second click
}
<input type="submit" />
```

As you'll can see I get error as true the first time I click on input and false the second time I click it.

I expect error to be false the first time I click on input does anyone know why it's true?

Note: My form is a nested form where I use FormContext to wrap my form so I can split the form into smaller components. Could it be that that's causing this side-effect or is it just something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Is this a typing error? `const useState[error, setError] = useState(true)`

Comment: Yeah it's a typing error. My bad I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, React is weird like that. `setError(false)` is running the first time and changing the state, but it's not guaranteed to be synchronous. So the console.log() right after it still has the old state.

[React hooks useState not updating with onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194317/react-hooks-usestate-not-updating-with-onchange)

Comment: Ah thank you! I did solve my issue by ditching useState but was still wondering why useState didn't work. This clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

React state changes are asynchronous. It is not guaranteed that you will get the most recent change in a synchronous `console.log`. The correct way of logging the value if you want to see the most recent change would be inside a `useEffect` hook.

```js
const [error, setError] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(error)
}, [error]);
```